# Need to develop PhoneGap app which will show a different PDF every week

Tags: android, pdf, cordova

I am developing a PhoneGap app which will show a PDF of a newsletter. I am linking to the externally hosted PDF from the app. The PDF will change every week. Obviously it is not practical to ask people to update the app every week, so I am looking for suggestions on how to go about this?
I had trouble getting PDF to display on android, but solved this by uploading the PDF to google drive and linking to the PDF on google drive. The fact that I need to use google drive eliminates the option of using a static link and uploading the latest PDF to the same destination (and with the same name obv) every week.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a PHP or ASP service on server which will give a `XML` or `json` response.

There you can update the new PDF link.

Make an call to those php or ASP service from your app, get the new pdf link (e.g. you can use jquery ajax call for this)